# Who do these wigs belong to?

Tags: comics, character-identification, image-comics, man-eaters

In issue #7 of the Image Comics series *Man-Eaters*, we get the following splash page with various hairstyles of iconic female pop-culture heroines:

[image: Wigs Splash page from Man-Eaters #7]

The numbers were added by me for easier identification.

Can you help me identify which character each wig belongs to?

Comment: Any reason for the down-votes?

Comment: Some people just don't like these sorts of identify questions anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Starting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit in more.

1. Princess Leia Organa, *Star Wars*
2. Hillary Clinton (?)
3. ?
4. ?
5. Daenerys Targaryen, *A Song of Ice and Fire*/*Game of Thrones*
6. Frida Kahlo (?)
7. Rey (?), *Star Wars*
8. Some variation of Medusa?
9. Usagi Tsukino, *Sailor Moon*
10. Marge Simpson, *The Simpsons*
11. Ariel (?), *The Little Mermaid*
12. Catwoman (Eartha Kitt), *Batman* '66
13. Rose Tico (?), *Star Wars*
14. Katara, *Avatar: The Last Airbender*
15. Harley Quinn, DC comics
16. ?
17. Alana, *Saga*
18. Wonder Woman, DC comics
19. Merida (?), *Brave*
20. Major Motoko Kusanagi, *Ghost in the Shell*
21. Storm, Marvel comics?

Comment: I thought 1 was Hillary Clinton before I realised it was fantasy characters.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I don't think it's all fantasy characters. It might be Hillary actually (she is featured prominently in #3 of the series).

Comment: #2 is definitely Hillary Clinton. But I'd like to read the original text from the page, because if this is about "hairstyles of iconic female pop-culture heroines", well...Jaime Lannister? Rey? Rose Tico :-D :-D :-D??!?!?! Katara, who? Lol...

Comment: @motoDrizzt If you go to con's, Katara and Rey are very popular cosplays. Rose and Jaime not so much.

Comment: @Parrotmaster "iconic female pop-culture heroines". If it was "randomly picked females", ok, but you can't label Katara or Rey as iconic pop-culture heroines just because a few hundreds humans on the planet like to cosplay them. Pop-culture is about being well known planet wide, not being completely obscure, and being an icon means that people actually consider that character relevant.

Comment: @motoDrizzt It's only "iconic female pop-culture heroines" according to the OP. I don't know if that is what they are actually referred to in the magazine.

Comment: @motoDrizzt `"hairstyles of iconic female pop-culture heroines", well...Jaime Lannister?` umm Jaime is a guy isn't he?

Comment: 12 is the Eartha Kitt version of Catwoman from the 1966 *Batman* series. I want to say 3 is maybe Imperator Furiosa from *Mad Max: Fury Road*? My first thought for 16 is Oprah Winfrey but does anyone cosplay as Oprah?

Comment: 4 is, I think, Josephine Baker, judging by a few of the pics I find in a Google image search for her.

Comment: Aha! I *knew* I had seen #17 somewhere in a comic book. It's Alana from *Saga*.

Comment: @PatrickWynne: yeah, definitely her.

Comment: #16 could be Misty Knight.